Problemas ao aplicar filtro de busca em uma tabela
Bom dia.
Criei uma tabela que puxa os dados do banco de dados, e no final dela, possui um ícone com uma função que, quando aperto pela primeira vez, ele registra a hora de entrada, e quando clico pela segunda vez, ele registra a hora de saída.
Mas estou tendo problemas ao aplicar um filtro de busca, pois quando o aplico e executo a função, ele remove o filtro e volta a exibir todos os dados, mas na verdade quero que permaneça o filtro até eu retirar.
Segue abaixo o html da página:
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px;">Perícias Agendadas</h1>
  <form name="form_listar_pericias" id="formListar" method="get">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; margin-left: 1px;">
      <tr style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <th>Data da Perícia</th>
        <th>Perito</th>
        <th>Periciado</th>
        <th>Processo</th>
        <th>Especialidade</th>
        <th>Situação da Perícia</th>
        <th>Compareceu à Perícia?</th>
        <th>Horário de Entrada</th>
        <th>Horário de Saída</th>
      </tr>
      <!--<tr>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Saída</button></td>
      </tr>-->
      {% for pericia in pericias %}
      <tr style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 1px; text-rendering: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
        <td>{{ pericia.data_pericia }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.perito }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.periciado }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.processo }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.especialidade }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.situacao_pericia }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" id="id_compareceu_pericia" name="compareceu_pericia" {% if pericia.compareceu_pericia %}checked{% endif %}></td>
        <td style="text-align: center">{{ pericia.hora_entrada|date:"H:i" }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">{{ pericia.hora_saida|date:"H:i" }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'atualizar_saida_pericia' pericia.id %}"><img src="{% static 'images/sair.png' %}" style="max-width: 15px; max-height: 15px; border: 0px;"></a></td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
  </form>
</div>
 
  <footer>
    <form method="GET">
      <div position="fixed" class="container-fluid">
        <span position="fixed" class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
          <a style="text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: small;">
            Data: <input type="text" placeholder="" name="search" id="search">
            Perito: <input type="text" name="perito" id="perito">
            Processo: <input type="text" name="processo" id="processo"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Buscar/Limpar</button></a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </footer>

Segue também a views.py onde contém a função do filtro:
def listagem_pericias(request):
 
    pericias = {
        'pericias': tbl_pericias_agendadas.objects.filter(situacao_pericia__icontains='Designada')
    }
    pericias = tbl_pericias_agendadas.objects.filter(situacao_pericia__icontains='Designada')
    busca = request.GET.get('search')
    busca1 = request.GET.get('perito')
    busca2 = request.GET.get('processo')
    if busca:
        pericias = tbl_pericias_agendadas.objects.filter(data_pericia__icontains=busca, perito__icontains=busca1, processo__icontains=busca2)
    if busca1:
        pericias = tbl_pericias_agendadas.objects.filter(data_pericia__icontains=busca, perito__icontains=busca1, processo__icontains=busca2)
    if busca2:
        pericias = tbl_pericias_agendadas.objects.filter(data_pericia__icontains=busca, perito__icontains=busca1, processo__icontains=busca2)
 
    return render(request, 'pericias_agendadas/listagem_pericias.html', {'pericias': pericias})

Em anexo (imagem), segue a foto do botão de saída, para melhor efeito de entendimento.
Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Modifique o link do ícone de registro de horários para incluir os parâmetros de busca atuais. Use a template tag 'url' do Django para gerar a URL com os parâmetros de busca. No Views não precisa mexer.


<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px;">Perícias Agendadas</h1>
  <form name="form_listar_pericias" id="formListar" method="get">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 15px; margin-left: 1px;">
      <tr style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <th>Data da Perícia</th>
        <th>Perito</th>
        <th>Periciado</th>
        <th>Processo</th>
        <th>Especialidade</th>
        <th>Situação da Perícia</th>
        <th>Compareceu à Perícia?</th>
        <th>Horário de Entrada</th>
        <th>Horário de Saída</th>
      </tr>
      {% for pericia in pericias %}
      <tr style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 1px; text-rendering: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
        <td>{{ pericia.data_pericia }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.perito }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.periciado }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.processo }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.especialidade }}</td>
        <td>{{ pericia.situacao_pericia }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" id="id_compareceu_pericia" name="compareceu_pericia" {% if pericia.compareceu_pericia %}checked{% endif %}></td>
        <td style="text-align: center">{{ pericia.hora_entrada|date:"H:i" }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">{{ pericia.hora_saida|date:"H:i" }}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="{% url 'atualizar_saida_pericia' pericia.id %}?search={{ request.GET.search }}&perito={{ request.GET.perito }}&processo={{ request.GET.processo }}">
            <img src="{% static 'images/sair.png' %}" style="max-width: 15px; max-height: 15px; border: 0px;">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <br />
  </form>
</div>

<footer>
  <form method="GET">
    <div position="fixed" class="container-fluid">
      <span position="fixed" class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
        <a style="text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: small;">
          Data: <input type="text" placeholder="" name="search" id="search">
          Perito: <input type="text" name="perito" id="perito">
          Processo: <input type="text" name="processo" id="processo"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Buscar/Limpar</button>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</footer>




Obrigado pela sugestão, mas ainda não resolveu o problema. Ainda continua removendo o filtro e listando todos os dados quando dou a primeira saída para atualizar o horário. Sabe o que mais posso tentar?
